# Slitherlink? I hardly know her!

Tags: grid-deduction, slitherlink

<sub>This puzzle is part of the [Monthly Topic Challenge #13: Variety Slitherlinks](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7488/monthly-topic-challenge-13-variety-slitherlinks).</sub>

---

Rules of hexagonal Slitherlink:

- Draw one continuous loop in the grid along dotted lines. The line cannot cross itself or branch out.
- Numbers in cells give how many of the cell's six sides is filled as part of the loop.

[Solve on Penpa+](https://tinyurl.com/2272aeqd)

[image: Empty hexagonal Slitherlink grid]

Comment: I really enjoy these kinds of deduction games (I've beaten CrossCells, SquareCells, HexCells/Plus/Infinite, Tametsi) but I'm feeling completely lost on this one. Is there a more simple tutorial that introduces this style of deduction? I feel like I'm completely missing the patterns here.

Comment: Also: On Penpa+ is there some better way to reset the board? "delete all" doesn't fix it, nor does a page refresh, nor does clearing cache.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A lot of fun!

> [image: Solution from penpa]

Not sure how much I can recreate of the solving process, but

> start with the two adjacent 5-cells the edge between them must be filled and the two absent edges have to be adjacent to the shared edge. Further the 4 cell above must have the upper 2 edges filled.

Then note

> Every unfinished edge has only two options for how to extend and no vertex can have three edges coming in.

Comment: The "2" in the 4th row from the top (kind of under and to the right of the "4") has three sides with a line on it

Comment: @ElGuapo <buries head in shame> Call it a typo? Corrected version now added (three edges changed)

Answer (score 4):

The final grid looks like this:

> [image]

I can provide a detailed solve path if required, but it was all basic deductions.
Curiously, I got the congratulations message from Penpa before I had a complete loop.

Comment: Argh, I must have had the "ignore lines on grid borders" option on, which explains the early message. Sorry about that!